# swing Задний план текста

Tags: java

подскажите пж, как сделать так, чтобы в текстовой панели, текст сидел бы по умолчанию. Например поле, и в нем бледными буквами написано "введите продукт". Я нажимаю и ввожу. Так скажем подсказка в текстовом поле. На картинке показано с визуальной точки зрения (но текст конечно же должен быть на заднем плане)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробуйте - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916255/how-to-display-a-default-message-in-jtextfield-java

Comment: спасибо большое